# JSQMessagesViewController Showing Usernames

Tags: ios, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I presently have the view:

[image]

I wish to allow showing the usernames of the users in chat, much like they have in the example as:

[image]

What methods must be used to allow this?

Comment: Are you talking about the little initials in the avatar bubble?

Comment: @NSGangster, yes the initials. How to map that to allow setting a possible username?

Answer (score 1):

You just need

If you look at the Demo for the project they use the `JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory avatarImageWithUserInitials:` and and pass in the initials right there.

found in the `DemoModelData.m`

```
JSQMessagesAvatarImage *jsqImage = [JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory avatarImageWithUserInitials:@"JSQ"
                                                                                  backgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.85f alpha:1.0f]
                                                                                        textColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.60f alpha:1.0f]
                                                                                             font:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f]
                                                                                         diameter:kJSQMessagesCollectionViewAvatarSizeDefault];
```

You can check out all the code. let me know if that is not what you are looking for. I am trying to build it out as a good resource to help with questions like this

Comment: In the example pictures I show they have initials in a colored bubble, not just the name, how is that configured?

Comment: Ahh your looking for the initials in the avatar view.

Comment: Yes, how is that formulated?

Comment: Why didn't you change the picture?

Comment: Is there a swift implementation?

Comment: Ya it has been added to the project.

Comment: It is not present at: https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController, where is the swift demo with the usernames?

Comment: It is still in review but you can checkout the branch and see how it is done. https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/pull/1605